# Stripe customer portal not accepting session variable

Tags: python, stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

```
@auth.route('/create-customer-portal-session', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def customer_portal():

   getting = db.child('users').child(session['account_name']).get()
   getting = json.loads(json.dumps(getting.val()))

   session = stripe.billing_portal.Session.create(
   customer=getting['customer_id'],
   return_url=YOUR_DOMAIN,
   )
   print(session.url)
   return redirect(session.url, code=303)
```

My session variable is assigned during the login or sign up phase and can't be used.
This is the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'session' referenced before assignment"
I have no problems using this session variable across the website.

It's important to be able to access the variable as it's what i use to get the stripe customer id value

Comment: Can you share the ID (req_xxx) of the failing API request?
<https://support.stripe.com/questions/finding-the-id-for-an-api-request>
Can you share the complete Stacktrace of the error/response ?

Comment: req_8xXpC3xjf0tBtO This is what i'm trying to do. this is from an example of where i hard code the username, however, I never reach the portal using the session variable, it throws the unboundlocal error first

Comment: That request is successful... I invite you to reach out to Discord server and chat there: https://stripe.com/go/developer-chat